# How to find the point measurement of the laser light in a vertical plane using OpenCV in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, detection, measurement

I wanted to find the measurement or the point of the laser light which touches that plane using OpenCV and display the measurement. I searched for many resources regarding this use case but unfortunately, I could not find anything. I will attach an image for more clarification of my use case.

the image:

[image]

If you have a vertical plane and you have a laser light. and you hit this laser light to any place on the vertical plane, then using the camera and OpenCV, it should be able to **detect the particular point or the reading of the vertical plane that the laser light has touched in millimeters and display the value on the screen**.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: perhaps you should start with a camera and a real picture.